# PHP Find Array Index value in multi-line array

Tags: php

I have a multi-line array value setup in existing code (written by an former team member) as follows:

```
$array1['Alpha'] = "New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
$array1['Beta'] = "New York,Los Angeles,Honolulu";
$array1['Gamma'] = "New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
....
....
and so on....
```

My need is that I have the value of a city (say "Washington"), and I need to get all the array index values which have Washington in their CSV list.
So in the above case, the answer would be "Alpha" and "Gamma" (but not "Beta" as it does not contain Washington)

I tried array_search function, like

```
echo array_search("Washington",$array1);
```

but it is not yielding the desired result.

What am I missing here please?

Also tried

```
$cittskarray = explode(',', $array1["Washington"]);

foreach ($array1 as $cityvalue)
{
 ;//search one by one
}
```

but that is lengthy method and does deep search.

Comment: _"What am I missing here please?"_ - how array_search actually works ...? Quote manual: _"Searches the array for a given value"_ - but none of your array values actually _is_ `Washington`

Comment: @CBroe - got it. I was also trying explode function on each array value, but the code was getting lengthier and complex. So looking for an efficient solution. Additional question I had is what really is this multi-line array? Is it associative hash, or what as per PHP standard?

Comment: It is a normal, _flat_ array. You don't have more than one dimension here to begin with. All of your values are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `foreach` and check as:

1. You can convert comma separated string to array, and check using `in_aray`
2. if that value found, then you can fill in new output array.

See below example

```
$array1['Alpha']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
$array1['Beta']="New York,Los Angeles,Honolulu";
$array1['Gamma']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";

$returnData = [];
foreach ($array1 as $k => $val)
{
 $datas = explode(",",$val);
    if(in_array('Washington', $datas) ){
        $returnData[] = $k;
    }
}

print_r($returnData);
```

Output will be: `[0] => Alpha [1] => Gamma`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `array_search` looks for full match.

Simply loop array and check existence of search string:

```php
$array1['Alpha']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
$array1['Beta']="New York,Los Angeles,Honolulu";
$array1['Gamma']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";

$keyword = 'Washington';

foreach ($array1 as $key => $cities)
{
   if (str_contains($cities, $keyword)) {
        echo $key . "\n";
   }
}
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81bf7ca06d4d1093a88ebfa1f4ebc038d47d9328)

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, This only works on PHP versions which are at least 8.0.0. My server is unfortunately lower

Comment: @Aquaholic So replace `str_contains` with `stripos($cities, $keyword) !== false`

Comment: Yes. That works. Thanks (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the most efficient way, but you could use `array_filter()` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php)) to acheive this.

Example :

```
<?php
$array['Alpha']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
$array['Beta']="New York,Los Angeles,Honolulu";
$array['Gamma']="New York,Los Angeles,Washington";
$search = "Washington";

$result = array_keys(array_filter($array, function($a) use ($search) {
    return strpos($a, $search) > -1;
}));

print_r($result);
```

Where the function is an anonymous function (so could be changed), will display:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alpha
    [1] => Gamma
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Frankich. Your code works well (+1), and the one by DevsiOdedra is comparatively more clear and readable.